# What does this cell size mean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, resolution, bhuvan

I wanted to check the cell size of a DEM I downloaded from http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan_links.php# cartosat cartodem version3.

I wanted to check its resolution and on opening layers properties, it showed `0.0002777778` as you can see in this picture. What size resolution does this mean, and why is it that it's not showing the resolution in meters?

[image]

Comment: What is the projection used and what are the units? Seeing that it is recognised as TIFF (and not geotiff), this data might be hidden somewhere else (e.g. data description or similar).

Comment: Cell size is expressed in the units which are defined for the projection. I guess you have data in EPSG:4326 and the values are in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The data you show is likely to be displayed in decimal degrees. If it is in decimal degrees it is not showing the resolution in meters because you have stored the data in a Geographic Coordinate System rather than a Projected Geographic Coordinate System and therefore units are in angles.

I would recommend setting the data frame in an ArcMap map document to a Projected Geographic Coordinate System that you know the data is meant to be placed and see if that changes the units to the units defined in the Coordinate System.